# can't use elastic-beanstalk and beautiful soup

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, beautifulsoup

my goal is to be able to use beutifulsoup4 with Python3.4 in a flask web-app all with a elastic-beanstalk server and be able to use beautifulsoup  within my main script. I have succeeded in getting a elastic beanstalk web app with flask and python 3.4 up and running smoothly with this code:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
# print a nice greeting.
def say_hello(username = "World"):
    return '<p>Hello %s!</p>\n' % username

# some bits of text for the page.
header_text = '''
    <html>\n<head> <title>EB Flask Test</title> </head>\n<body>'''
instructions = '''
    <p><em>Hint</em>: This is a RESTful web service! Append a username
    to the URL (for example: <code>/Thelonious</code>) to say hello to
    someone specific.</p>\n'''
home_link = '<p><a href="/">Back</a></p>\n'
footer_text = '</body>\n</html>'

# EB looks for an 'application' callable by default.
application = Flask(__name__)

# add a rule for the index page.
application.add_url_rule('/', 'index', (lambda: header_text +
    say_hello() + instructions + footer_text))

# add a rule when the page is accessed with a name appended to the site
# URL.
application.add_url_rule('/<username>', 'hello', (lambda username:
    header_text + say_hello(username) + home_link + footer_text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

requirements file looks like this:

```
flask==0.12.2
beautifulsoup4==4.6
lxml==4.1
```

up until this point every thing is OK with no errors, but once I import beautifulsoup in line 3 of the python code the web page gives me this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable 
to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

if anyone is able to provide advice or let me know if i am being to broad pleas let me know:)

thanks again, john D.

Comment: I don't see an import for Beautiful Soup. It should look like `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. Also, I'm not sure how you would look at the web server logs on Elastic Beanstalk, but you should do that and post any additional info you find there.

Comment: thanks so much for the response! importing it differently did not do anything different, i checked the server logs and it says this : ImportError: No module named 'bs4'